# Setting current date and default time in angular datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to set the default date to current date and customize default time in a datepicker using Angular, e.g Current date: 07-02-2020 and default custom time should be 08:00 AM. How can i achieve this please. Here is my html code which only shows date and time based on value selected.

```
   <label class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 form-control-label  ml-2" for="date_from">{{'From Date' | 
  translate}} <span class="danger">*</span>:</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="datetime-local" [(ngModel)]="leaveList.date_from" 
  [max]="leaveList.date_to" class="form-control input-md" id="date_from" 
                    name="date_from" (change)="onChangeDate()"  max="9999-12-31">
                </div>
```

.component.ts file

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `moment` library for date/time formatting

1-install moment using `npm i moment`

2-You have to assign value to date_from in your `.ts`, just like that

`leaveList.date_from = moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY 8:30A')`

Comment: Thanks @ahmed, I want it to show the current date as default, but a static time . e.g 07-02-2020: 8:30AM should show once the page loads. The date part should be dynamic according to the current date but the time should be static

Comment: you have to use moment for formatting,check my edit

Comment: You are correct, but i want to show the default time, so the user can click and select, but default date and time should be shown on the screen before the user selects from the datepicker. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input required class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="myDate" type="datetime-local" name="myDate" id="myDate"/>
```

you can customize the date as you want instead of using new Date()

```js
this.myDate = this.datepipe.transform(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm'),
```

so you have to import DatePipe

```js
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common'
```

and initialize in the constructor

```js
constructor(public datepipe: DatePipe){
}
```

and also add it int the app.module.ts as a provider

```js
providers: [
    DatePipe,
    ....
],
```

read more https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe